# How to list the event of the etw DX provider?

Tags: etw, dx

I find a method that use wevtutil to get the publisher configuration information. For example i use commond "wevtutil gp Microsoft-Windows-DiagCpl /ge:true /gm:true /f:xml" . But when i use commond "wevtutil gp DX /ge:true /gm:true /f:xml", the result is "Failed to open metadata for publisher DX". It mean the DX is not a publisher, So i use "wevtutil ep" commond to list the all publisher, and i cant find DX. But I use commond "xperf -providers" to list all providers, and DX is contained. I want to know how to get the DX provider's configuration information.Help me .

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked a year ago, but I just happened to see it now.  Anyway, here goes...

Are you sure "DX" is the full name of the provider or the provider you're looking to get the metadata?  Using logman, I see:
    Microsoft-Windows-DxgKrnl
and Microsoft-Windows-DXGI
but not just "DX".

The mentioned wevtutil command works with two those providers.